# Visual Studio 2019: Linking to folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include-path

I am trying to link to a folder that is not inside the project directory. To give an example,

If my project is in `C:\project` and I have a folder `C:\shared`, how can I manage to link `C:\shared` into the project (and being able to edit/view the files in Solution Explorer) without making a copy of the directory and placing it into the project directory.

I need this due to the fact that many projects will use this folder and it would be ideal to have them edit/use the same files rather than copy the folder into each project individually. That way if a bug is fixed in one project, all other projects will now use the fixed files as well.

For more context, this is a C++ project using Visual Studio 2019.

What I've tried/considered.

1. Additional include directories

- Problem: This does not show the files in the Solution Explorer

2. Dragging/dropping the folder (or copy/pasting) as seen in another StackOverflow thread.

- Problem: This just crashes my visual studio completely. The folder is quite large so I assume that's related to why.

Appreciate any insight on how to proceed. It's really unfortunate that this is a pain, I would think that something like this would be common, but all the posts I've seen related to it have either gone unanswered or could not be applied to my situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you want to bundle all of that outside of project stuff into a library and then link  the library. That way all your program cares about is setting the include path in the C\C++ options to point at the library's headers and adding a library to the Linker Input property page.

Comment: @user4581301 I don't know if that's what I want. I want to be able to edit the shared files on all projects. Having to link the library on each project seems like an inconvenience, especially if I have to build the include project each time. Maybe I am misunderstanding you? Ideally I just want this to act as a normal folder that can be viewed in the Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shared Projects are the key here.. I just found out they existed. After creating one, drop the folder/files in the same directory that has .vcxitems file. Now in the project you want to include the shared folder, right click your solution, Add -> Existing Project and select your .vcxitems file.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.